# Randomize the UV of an object with an array modifier?

Tags: texturing, uv, modifiers

Can I randomize the UV of an object with an array modifier I'm try to make stairs using an array but with same uv texture, I don't like how it looks.

[[image: sample image[1]]?

Answer (score 1):

Try U-Offset/V-Offset in Array Modifier.